# XSLT sort issue - attribute wont sort

Tags: xslt, svg

Source

```
<roll>
  <dayquantum date="20130125">
    <item index="2" value="4" product="Margherita"/>
    <item index="3" value="2" product="Capricciosa"/>
    <item index="4" value="2" product="Quattro Stagioni"/>
    <item index="5" value="7" product="Bresola"/>
    <item index="6" value="1" product="Gorgonzola"/>
    <item index="7" value="7" product="Piccante"/>
    <item index="8" value="3" product="Rosmarino"/>
    <item index="9" value="2" product="Caprese"/>
    <item index="10" value="7" product="Parma"/>
    <item index="11" value="1" product="Parmigiana"/>
    <item index="12" value="2" product="Pollo"/>
    <item index="13" value="2" product="Hawaii"/>
    <item index="14" value="17" product="Pepperoni"/>
    <item index="15" value="4" product="Calzone"/>
    <item index="16" value="2" product="Bologna"/>
    <item index="17" value="3" product="Tonno"/>
    <item index="18" value="1" product="Marinara"/>
    <item index="19" value="2" product="Napoletana"/>
    <item index="20" value="1" product="Carne"/>
    <item index="21" value="1" product="Mascarpone"/>
    <item index="22" value="4" product="Carpaccio"/>
    <item index="25" value="1" product="Tartufo"/>
    <item index="26" value="8" product="Prosciutto"/>
    <item index="27" value="3" product="Lasagna Originale"/>
    <item index="28" value="1" product="Tortellini Gorgonzola"/>
    <item index="29" value="1" product="Tortellini Tartufo"/>
    <item index="31" value="4" product="Tagliatelle Dolce Vita"/>
    <item index="33" value="1" product="Spaghetti Carbonara"/>
    <item index="37" value="2" product="Antipasta Toto e Pepino"/>
    <item index="38" value="1" product="Vitello Tonnato"/>
    <item index="41" value="4" product="Bruschetta classica"/>
    <item index="44" value="1" product="Tiramisu"/>
    <item index="47" value="4" product="Panino al Pollo"/>
    <item index="48" value="5" product="Panino al Prosciutto"/>
    <item index="49" value="8" product="Panino al vitello tonnato"/>
  </dayquantum>
</roll>
```

XSLT

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2400 1400" style="background: #000 ; font-family: 'Racing Sans One'"  id="zcanvas" version="1.1" xsl:version="1.0"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs><link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Racing+Sans+One|Six+Caps" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></defs>  

    <xsl:for-each select="roll/dayquantum">
      <xsl:sort select="@date" order="descending" data-type="number"/>

      <xsl:variable name="y" select="(position() * 180) - 100" />    

      <text fill="#fff" font-size="48">      
        <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="80" /></xsl:attribute>            
        <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="$y - 40" /></xsl:attribute>        
        <xsl:attribute name="transform">rotate(90, 80, <xsl:value-of select="$y - 40 " />)</xsl:attribute>                      
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(@date,7,2)" /><xsl:value-of select="substring('  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC', number(substring(@date,5,2)) * 3, 3)" />          
      </text>
      <text fill="#ff6000" font-size="48">      
        <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="120" /></xsl:attribute>            
        <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="$y - 10" /></xsl:attribute>        
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(item/@value)" />
      </text>

      <xsl:for-each select="item">     
        <xsl:sort select="@value" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <rect fill="green" >      
          <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="200 + (sum(preceding-sibling::item/@value) * 16)" /></xsl:attribute>            
          <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="$y - 48" /></xsl:attribute>        
          <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="@value * 16" /></xsl:attribute>            
          <xsl:attribute name="rx">10</xsl:attribute>        
          <xsl:attribute name="height">48</xsl:attribute>        
        </rect>
        <g font-family="sans-serif">
        <text fill="#fff" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle">      
          <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="200 + (sum(preceding-sibling::item/@value) * 16) + ((@value * 16) div 2)" /></xsl:attribute>            
          <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="$y - 20" /></xsl:attribute>          
          <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </text>       
        <text fill="#888" font-size="18" text-anchor="start">      
          <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="200 + (sum(preceding-sibling::item/@value) * 16) + ((@value * 16) div 2)" /></xsl:attribute>            
          <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="$y" /></xsl:attribute>          
          <xsl:attribute name="transform">rotate(90, <xsl:value-of select="200 + (sum(preceding-sibling::item/@value) * 16) + ((@value * 16) div 2)" />, <xsl:value-of select="$y" />)</xsl:attribute>            
          <xsl:value-of select="@product" />
        </text>
        </g>
      </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:for-each>  
    </svg>
```

Problem:

It won't sort on attribute "value" descending - is it because of preceeding statement ?

Source can be found here: http://xmlsoap.dk/xml/crCountLog.xml

Comment: i expect the item' is presented in a descending fashion
i.e the items with the highest numerical value in the beginning
it is SVG and you should see result in non-ie browser ...
You're right - i have syncronised XSLt and the above ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it's not working the way you expect is that `preceding-sibling::` looks at the `item`s' preceding siblings in *document order*, not the current sort order. So they are being sorted, but the `x` values are being computed as though you had not sorted them at all.

The following recursive approach should achieve what you are trying to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2400 1400"
         style="background: #000 ; font-family: 'Racing Sans One'"  id="zcanvas"
         version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Racing+Sans+One|Six+Caps"
              type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </defs>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="roll/dayquantum">
        <xsl:sort select="@date" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dayquantum">
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="(position() * 180) - 100" />

    <text fill="#fff" font-size="48" x="80" y="{$y - 40}"
          transform="rotate(90, 80, {$y - 40})">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(@date,7,2)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring('  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC', 
                            number(substring(@date,5,2)) * 3, 3)" />
    </text>
    <text fill="#ff6000" font-size="48" x="120" y="{$y - 10}">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(item/@value)" />
    </text>

    <xsl:variable name="topItem" select="item[not(../item/@value > @value)][1]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$topItem">
      <xsl:with-param name="y" select="$y" />
      <xsl:with-param name="remainingItems" 
                      select="item[generate-id() != generate-id($topItem)]" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:param name="y" />
    <xsl:param name="previousItems" select="/.." />
    <xsl:param name="remainingItems" />

    <xsl:variable name="leadingSpace"
                  select="200 + sum($previousItems/@value) * 16" />
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="@value * 16" />
    <xsl:variable name="hCenter" select="$leadingSpace + $width div 2" />

    <rect fill="green" x="{$leadingSpace}" y="{$y - 48}" width="{$width}"
          rx="10" height="48" />

    <g font-family="sans-serif">
      <text fill="#fff" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" x="{$hCenter}"
            y="{$y - 20}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      </text>

      <text fill="#888" font-size="18" text-anchor="start" x="{$hCenter}"
            y="{$y}" transform="rotate(90, {$hCenter}, {$y})">
        <xsl:value-of select="@product" />
      </text>
    </g>

    <xsl:variable name="topItem"
               select="$remainingItems[not($remainingItems/@value > @value)][1]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$topItem">
      <xsl:with-param name="y" select="$y" />
      <xsl:with-param name="previousItems" select="$previousItems | ." />
      <xsl:with-param name="remainingItems"
                      select="$remainingItems[generate-id() != 
                                                generate-id($topItem)]" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This approach selects the first item with no items less than itself, and applies templates to only that, passing the remaining items as parameters. Then the next top item is selected and the template recursively calls itself, repeatedly until all of the items have been used up.

Comment: You're welcome. And I think you need to be _more_ lazy and use more attribute value templates instead of all those unsightly `<xsl:attributes>`. :)  That's quite a nifty page you're working on there. I should start learning about SVG one of these days.

Comment: i noticed your minimalisic approach - yeah I like to do SVG  

inspiration: http://xmlsoap.dk/cashregister/cr.xml
personal analysis of banktransactions - you can click on dots in the bottom
http://www.mrasch.dk/analyseTransactions2006_2010.xml
regards mike